# Jenkins - Unable to access the parameter sent from one build pipeline in another build pipeline using "build job" command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

I have a pipeline project say "A" which is string parameterized, and I am trying to call another build say "B" which is also string parameterized, using the command as follows :

build job: 'B', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'tagg', value: "$env.tag"]]

The target is used to pass the parameter which was taken as input from A and assign use it in B.I tried to receive the parameter echo "$env.tagg" which gave null, echo "$tagg" gave no such parameter found error.

So how do I receive the parameters sent from A in B.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to let Jenkins know what env.tag is, try something like:

```
build job: 'B', parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'tagg', value: String.ValueOf($env.tag)]]
```

Comment: It is giving the following error:groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: $env for class: groovy.lang.Binding

Comment: Please post your whole Jenkinsfile